# Solr Multi Select Facting ignoring Other Selected Facets

Tags: solr, multi-select, facet

I am working on facets for a solr search result.  I am having trouble getting the facets to display how I want them.  I would like to be able to select a value in one facet and have only the counts update in the other facets without taking values away when the facet count is 0.
Example
I did a search for shirt and here are the facets that are returned with their counts:

Color:
[ ] Red (10)
[ ] Blue (10)
[ ] Green (10)

Size:
[ ] Small (5) 
[ ] Medium (10)
[ ] Large (10)

Now if I select the color red I want my facets to update as such:

Color:
[x] Red (10)
[ ] Blue (10)
[ ] Green (10)

Size:
[ ] Small (0) 
[ ] Medium (5)
[ ] Large (5)

I have it working so that selecting a color does not limit the options in the color facet, but I can't work out how to get the proper facets to display for size, by tweaking the excludes I either get:

Size:
[ ] Medium (5)
[ ] Large (5)
or:
Size:
[ ] Small (5) 
[ ] Medium (10)
[ ] Large (10)

I have tried adding the facet.limit=-1 but it doesn't seem to do anything, maybe a bug as I was expecting this to do what I was looking for?  I am running solr 4.3.1.

Here is my query: 
q=chair&rows=10&start=0&facet.limit=-1&defType=edismax&facet.field={!ex=colortag}color&facet.field={!ex=sizetag}size&facet=true&fq={!tag=colortag}color:red&fl=*,score

Is this possible with Solr?  I have not come across any examples of this and am worried that the solution would be to handle it on the front end with caching which won't work.

**Edit**

So I added the facet.mincount=0 which did and did not give me what I wanted.  The issue is that with setting the mincount to 0 now I get all facets that are not part of the search result.  So here is what I want:

Color:
[x] Red (10)
[ ] Blue (10)
[ ] Green (10)

Size:
[ ] Small (0) 
[ ] Medium (5)
[ ] Large (5)

but what I am actually getting is:

Color:
[x] Red (10)
[ ] Blue (10)
[ ] Green (10)
[ ] Orange (0)
[ ] Purple (0)
[ ] Pink (0)

Size:
[ ] Small (0) 
[ ] Medium (5)
[ ] Large (5)
[ ] X-Large (0) 
[ ] XX-Large (0)

So now I have added colors and sizes that don't match the query term.  I realize it is working correctly but it's not how I want it to work.  Is there another approach that I can take.  I do realize I could make one call to get the initial results without any selected facets and then do a second call to get the filtered facets and then compare and build out the correct result.  I would rather not do a double call, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: solution you used is proper, just use `facet.mincount=0` or the other values to get the facet value with that count, and if you don't need to exclude for size then you should remove exclusion on size facets

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Do not exclude for the facet of `size`, use `facet.mincount=0` with `facet.limit`

```
   q=chair&rows=10&start=0&facet.limit=-1&defType=edismax&facet.field={!ex=colortag}color&facet.field=size&facet=true&fq={!tag=colortag}color:red&fl=*,score
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not absolute solution. Use facet.mincount =0 , Try also setting facet.size.mincount=0.

You can read more about it here : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters